Enthalpy Change in Reversible Isothermal Process
This is with reference to the following question from JEE Advanced 2024 Paper 1 : 
The solution to this is by taking $\pu{\Delta H = 0}$ in process XY due to it being isothermal, then applying $\pu{\Delta H = nC_pdT}$ for process YZ which is isochoric ($\pu{w = 0}$).
I understand that enthalpy ($\pu{nC_pdT}$) is a state function, and depends only upon final & initial temperature, but if we go by
$$\pu{\Delta H = Delta U +(-w)}$$
with $\pu{\Delta U = nCvdT = 0}$ for $\pu{dT = 0}$ i.e. isothermal process, we get $\pu{\Delta H = - W}$.
At the same time, we know for reversible isothermal process $\pu{ w = -nRTln(\frac{V_2}{V_1})}$.
By this logic, we get $\pu{H = -W = nRTln(\frac{V_2}{V_1}) \neq 0}$.
I know I'm missing something here, but I can't understand what.
I looked at the following posts here, to no avail:

Enthalpy change in an isothermal experiment at constant pressure
What would be the enthalpy change for a isothermal expansion?


In context of physical chemistry, we consider W as work done on the system, not by the system (as used in engineering, and was mostly used in physics until recently).

In the isothermal step, $\Delta H$ is not equal to $\Delta U+W$.  It is equal to $\Delta U+\Delta (PV)=0$;  the heat added Q is equal to the work done by the gas.

Thank you for your answer. But if we look at the question I've attached, in process XY, there is a change in volume of the gas. I get that the pressure must be compensating it at every instant, but isn't that how we get the work done in isothermal process formula? If we have delta(PV)=0, shouldn't work done in isothermal process also be zero?

Also, if work is being done by gas, meaning heat has been given, won't that reflect in enthalpy change?

No.  The energy to make the gas expand is furnished by heat from the surroundings.

I was going through my textbook, and it finally clicked. I was confusing q with deltaH. Just to confirm, as you said, the heat added will be equal to the work done, so net change in q for the process ie. enthalpy change will be 0. Thank you.
